# How to setup KoaJS in Openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift, koa

I've been following the example on how to enable custom node version in openshif (http://www.zev23.com/2014/04/openshift-harmony-nodejs.html) so when I ssh to the application I can see the node version(0.11.14) installed but the when I look at the logs  it says
`app.use(function *(){` ... `SyntaxError: Unexpected token *` and I'm getting a 503 error.

here's my server.js file:

```
var koa = require('koa');
var app = module.exports = koa();

app.use(function *(){
  this.body = 'Hello World';
});

var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
if (typeof ipaddress === "undefined") {
   //  Log errors on OpenShift but continue w/ 127.0.0.1 - this
   //  allows us to run/test the app locally.
   console.warn('No OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP var, using 127.0.0.1');
   ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";
};
if (!module.parent) app.listen(port, ipaddress);
```

I've also added 0.11.14 in the `NODEJS_VERSION` inside

__ UPDATE __

I've check the server using ssh it says node 0.11.14 but when I added these lines( see below) before my actual web application starts it seams like it's running on node 0.10.25 and the path that was set in the .bash_profile is not the one being use in the path.

```
var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
console.log(ipaddress, port);
console.log(process.versions);
console.log(process.env.PATH);
```

Is there a way to configure the PATH just before the actual application starts so it will use 0.11.14 instead of 0.10.25

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: are you running your `node` process with the `--harmony` flag to get all the new stuff enabled? use `node --v8-options` to get a list of possible switches; use `ps` or `htop` to check the command line `node` was started with.

Comment: Hello flow, thanks for your reply yes I've started my application with --harmony. I'm sorry to ask but can you give me examples on how to do this things in openshift. I've also check the server using ssh and run node -v and it says node 0.11.14 so --harmony should work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've followed the instruction in https://github.com/ramr/nodejs-custom-version-openshift and everything is now working. Just added `main: --harmony server.js` in package.json.