# OpenShift not working with certain Nodejs dependencies (Koa)

Tags: node.js, openshift, koa

I've checked out [How to setup KoaJS in Openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924967/how-to-setup-koajs-in-openshift) and it's still not working.

Here is a part of my `package.json` file:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.12.0",
    "npm": ">= 1.0.0"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "co-busboy": "^1.3.0",
    "forever": "^0.14.1",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "koa": "^0.18.1",
    "koa-logger": "^1.2.2",
    "koa-router": "^4.2.0",
    "koa-static": "^1.4.9",
    "path": "^0.11.14"
    },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "bundleDependencies": [], 
  "private": true,
  "main": "--harmony app.js"
```

And then to my `app.js` file.

This code works:

```
var http = require('http');
//var koa = require('koa');
//var app = koa();

var ip = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1',
    port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || '8080';

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(port, ip);
console.log('Server running at http://'+ip+':'+port+'/');
```

This does not work:

```
var http = require('http');
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();

var ip = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1',
    port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || '8080';

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(port, ip);
console.log('Server running at http://'+ip+':'+port+'/');
```

As you can see the only difference is that I have uncommented two lines.

Error:

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at fela-basickarl.rhcloud.com Port 80
```

Error logs on OpenShift state this:

```
...
.../app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:179
function *respond(next) {
         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
...
```

A big duh.

`console.log(process.versions);` reveals that I am using node `0.10.25`, even though I stated in `package.json` that I wish to use `>= 0.12.0`:

```
{ http_parser: '2.0',
  node: '0.10.25',
  v8: '3.14.5.10',
  ares: '1.9.1',
  uv: '0.10.23',
  zlib: '1.2.3',
  modules: '11',
  openssl: '1.0.0-fips' }
```

What is causing OpenShift to not use 0.12.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick deploy 0.12

https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/128-node-js-0-12

For people that whishes to deplot nodejs `0.12` use the link above, there's a button `Deploy`.

### 0.12.2

To deploy the specific version `0.12.2` copy the directory `.openshift` from `https://github.com/ryanj/nodejs-custom-version-openshift` and overwrite your current projects `.openshift` directory (I am presuming you are using OpenShifts git that was created when the app was created).

Navigate your way to `your-project/.openshift/markers/` and open the file `NODEJS_VERSION` and add `0.12.2` at the bottom. My file looks as so:

```
#  Uncomment one of the version lines to select the node version to use.
#  The last "non-blank" version line is the one picked up by the code in
#  .openshift/lib/utils
#  Default: 0.10.25
#
#  0.8.24
#  0.9.1
#  0.10.25
#  0.11.11
#  0.10.25
0.12.2
```

Then upload your project via git to OpenShift (be in your project root directory).

```
git add -A .
git commit -a -m "replaced .openshift directory"
git push
```

### --harmony flag?

as stated in [ECMAScript 6 features available in Node.js 0.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388885/ecmascript-6-features-available-in-node-js-0-12) --harmony flag is still needed for certain functions.

This means adding it too your `package.json file`, look at my question to see an example.