# How to upgrade NodeJS for my existing application on openshift?

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have an application running on OpenShift using NodeJS 0.10 but now I want to upgrade it to latest 0.12. I added to `package.json`:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.12.0",
    "npm": ">= 1.0.0"
  },
```

I also followed https://blog.openshift.com/any-version-of-nodejs-you-want-in-the-cloud-openshift-does-it-paas-style/ and got `NODEJS_VERSION` marker in `.openshift` folder.

I stopped app, started again but cant get it to run NodeJS 0.12. I tried to remove NodeJS cartridge but I get 'nodejs-0.10' cannot be removed message. I also follwed accepted answer [OpenShift not working with certain Nodejs dependencies (Koa)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848177/openshift-not-working-with-certain-nodejs-dependencies-koa) but when I get to openshift page it seems that I can only deploy new application but I just need to upgrade existing app.

Is there any way to upgrade existing app nodeJs version on openshift?

Answer (score 0):

Just to say that OpenShift is updating to NodeJS 5.10.
I didn't find documentation about that, but I have created an application few days ago and a new option is showing up when selecting the cartridge to use.
I can see both options:

**Node.js 0.10** *(first option)*

**Node.js (Latest)** *(last option)*

[image: Openshift - Selecting the cartridge]

[image: Openshift - Specs]

Maybe it's a good idea to test it!